# Ionic 1 working with iframe - Hide if there is no internet and reload when internet available

Tags: angularjs, iframe, ionic-v1

I am new to ionic and I am stuck on getting iframe to hide when there is no internet connection and reload when internet is back on ionic 1.

I've seen answers on ionic forum and here on stackoverflow like using navigator.online

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
alert('There is internet connection available');
 }
else{
alert('There is no internet connection available');
}
```

But the problem is i dont know how to connect that to the iframe.

www/js/app.js

```
ionic// Ionic Starter App

 // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving 
Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> 
attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
//if use wakanda platform
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','wakanda' ])


 .run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$location,$ionicScrollDelegate,
  $ionicPopup)   {
  // if(window.Connection) {
 //   if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
 //     alert('There is no internet connection available');
 //   }else{
 //     alert(navigator.connection.type);
 //   }
 // }else{
 //   alert('Cannot find Window n.Connection');
 // }

 if (navigator.onLine) {
   alert('There is internet connection available');
 }
 else{
   alert('There is no internet connection available');
  }


  /*************** forget password ****************/

 $rootScope.forget_password=function (){
    $ionicPopup.show({
    template: 'Enter your email address below.<label class="item item-input" 
   style="  height: 34px; margin-top: 10px;"><input  type="email"  /></label>',
    title: 'Forget Password',
    subTitle: ' ',
    scope: $rootScope,
    buttons: [
    {text: 'Send',
    type: 'button-clear dark-blue'},
    { text: 'Cancel' ,
    type: 'button-clear main-bg-color'},]
    });


};

   /*************** increment-decrement function ****************/
   $rootScope.valueKids=1;
   $rootScope.valueAdults=1;
   $rootScope.valueBabies=1;
  $rootScope.increment_val= function(type) {
if (type=='Kids'&&$rootScope.valueKids >= 0) $rootScope.valueKids++;
if (type=='Adults'&&$rootScope.valueAdults >= 0) $rootScope.valueAdults++;
if (type=='Babies'&&$rootScope.valueBabies >= 0) $rootScope.valueBabies++;
 };
$rootScope.decrement_val = function(type) {
//if ($rootScope.value > 0)  $rootScope.value--;
if (type=='Kids'&&$rootScope.valueKids > 0) $rootScope.valueKids--;
if (type=='Adults'&&$rootScope.valueAdults > 0) $rootScope.valueAdults--;
if (type=='Babies'&&$rootScope.valueBabies > 0) $rootScope.valueBabies--;

 };

 $rootScope.confirmMsg=function(index){
 $rootScope.show_msg=index
 }

 $rootScope.scrollTop = function() {
   $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
 };
  /*************** group function ****************/
  $rootScope.groups = [
{id: 1, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]},

{id: 2, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]},

{id: 3, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]},

{id: 4, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]},

{id: 5, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]},

{id: 6, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]},

{id: 7, items: [{ subName: 'SubBubbles1'}]}
 ];


/*
 * if given group is the selected group, deselect it
 * else, select the given group
 */
 $rootScope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
if ($rootScope.isGroupShown(group)) {
  $rootScope.shownGroup = null;
} else {
  $rootScope.shownGroup = group;
}
 };
 $rootScope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
return $rootScope.shownGroup === group;
 };

 /*************** location function ****************/
 $rootScope.goto=function(url){
  $location.path(url)
 }

 /*************** active function ****************/
$rootScope.activeIcon=1
$rootScope.activeTab=function(index){
  $rootScope.activeIcon=index
  }
   /*************** repeat array ****************/
    $rootScope.menu =[{id:"1",img:"img/1.png",title:"Book 
  Flight",name:"right",link:"#/app/search"},
                    {id:"2",img:"img/2.png",title:"Manage 
 Booking",link:"#/app/reservations"},

 {id:"3",img:"img/3.png",title:"Destinations",link:"#/app/offer"},
                    {id:"4",img:"img/4.png",title:"Plan 
Trip",link:"#/app/register"},
                    {id:"5",img:"img/5.png",title:"Contact 
 Us",link:"#/app/contact"},
                    {id:"6",img:"img/6.png",title:"About 
 Us",link:"#/app/about"}]

    $rootScope.det =[{id:"1"},
                    {id:"2"}]

   $rootScope.data =[{id:"1"},
                    {id:"2"},{id:"3"},{id:"4"},{id:"5"}]

 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
 });
})

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {

  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
   $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').previousTitleText('');


  $stateProvider

  .state('home', {
   url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
   })

  .state('app', {
   url: "/app",
abstract: true,
templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
controller: 'AppCtrl'
 })

 .state('app.search', {
  url: "/search",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/search.html"
  }
}
  })

.state('app.payment', {
url: "/payment",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/payment.html"
  }
  }
  })

 .state('app.contact', {
url: "/contact",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
  }
  }
 })

 .state('app.reservations', {
url: "/reservations",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/reservations.html"
  }
  }
 })

 .state('app.details', {
url: "/details",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/details.html"
  }
}
 })

 .state('app.data', {
url: "/data",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/data.html"
  }
}
  })

 .state('app.offer', {
url: "/offer",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/offer.html"
  }
}
 })

 .state('app.register', {
url: "/register",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/register.html"
  }
}
 })

.state('app.about', {
url: "/about",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
  }
}
});
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');



 });
```

search.html

```
 <ion-content class="search_content padding" scroll="false" style="background- 
color: darkred">
  <div class="tab-content animated fadeInUp">
    <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 100%">
    <iframe name="chatFrame" id="iframe"
 class="iframe" style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; 
 BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none;width:100%;min- 
 height:290px" src="https://example.com" align="top" scrolling="auto">

        </iframe>

    </ion-scroll>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The ionic3 SDK is paired with angular 4 but the code here is AngularJS (1.x).

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I have an iframe that renders in an ionic application. I want the iframe to hide when there is no internet connection and reload if internet connection is back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maintain one flag in controller like below.

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
   $scope.isNetworkAvailable = true;
 }
 else{
   $scope.isNetworkAvailable = false;
}
```

Use that **isNetworkAvailable**  flag in HTML like below

```
<iframe ng-if="isNetworkAvailable " name="chatFrame" id="iframe"
 class="iframe" style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; 
 BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none;width:100%;min- 
 height:290px" src="https://example.com" align="top" scrolling="auto">

        </iframe>
```